# rubymine colors used in editor are different than selected in settings

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

I noticed that intellij/rubymine themes, are flawed. Monokai colors arent actually being used as provided. Is it possible to easily fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, RubyMine on Mac OS X renders everything through Quartz, which applies a level of gamma correction to the displayed picture. You can change this by editing Contents/Info.plist in the RubyMine.app package and changing the value of the apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz VM option to false.

Note that it will also affect font antialiasing, graphics performance and other aspects of the graphics output.

Comment: thanks for info, I ended up manually adjusting monokai colors :/